# Changing limits of integration

Tags: integration

Is that true, that for every function $f(x)$ changing the limits for opposite, 
causes:

$$\int^0_{-a} f(x) dx  = \int_0^a f(-x) dx$$

Comment: If the integral exists, yes.

Answer (score 3):

change variables to $u = -x, du = -dx$ in the right-hand integral to get
$$
\int_0^a f(-x)dx = -\int_0^{-a} f(u) du = \int_{-a}^0 f(u) du.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int^0_{-a}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int^{-0}_{-(-a)}f(-x)\mathrm{d}(-x)=\int^{a}_0f(-x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 0):

Integration by substitution states, in your case, that $\int_{\phi(0)}^{\phi(a)} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(\phi(t)) \phi'(t) dt$ for a continuously differentiable function $\phi$. Now if you choose $\phi(t) = -t$, then $\int_{-a}^{0} f(x) dx = - \int_{0}^{-a} f(x) dx = - \int_{0}^{a} -f(-t) dt = \int_{0}^{a} f(-t) dt$.

The "counterexamples" with an even f are invalid. In fact, $\int_0^a f(x) dx = \int_{-a}^0 f(x) dx$ though written as an inequality in another answer, exactly because it was assumed that f is an even function.